# show the function with the text on the tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying to show the predicted value on the tkinter GUI, but I couldn't find any way to show it on the screen, it's only shown on the console. Someone, please tell me how can I print that predicted text available in function on my GUI.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sounddevice as sound 
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
import time
import wavio as wv

app = Tk()
app.geometry("500x500")
app.title("Speaker Recognition System")
app.configure(bg = '#3c446b')
app.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')



 #background image work   
load= PhotoImage(file='images\\backg1.png')
img = Label(app, image=load)
img.place(x=0, y=0)

#labelwork
Label(text="Voice Recognition System",font="arial 28 bold", bg='black',fg='orange').pack(padx=5,pady=5)

print_classname(filename) <=


img4= PhotoImage(file='images\\exit.png')
btn4=Button(app, image = img4,bg='black', border=0,command=app.destroy)
btn4.place(x=290,y=170)

app.mainloop()
```

**The text that I want to show on the GUI is mentioned with the arrow**

Comment: One way to display the text would be to create another Label, just like the one that's displaying "Voice Recognition System".

Comment: But how can I call a function in that label?

Comment: `text=a_function()` perhaps - the parameter will take any expression, it doesn't have to be a literal string.

Comment: ```Label(text=print_classname(filename),font="arial 28 bold", bg='black',fg='orange').pack(padx=5,pady=5)
``` I tried this, but it is still printing that value on the console rather than showing it on screen.

Comment: The function need to `return` the value rather than printing it.

Comment: It worked, Thanks!